# POWER APPS- AI builder Credits

Tags: powerapps

Currently i have organization with 10k+ credits, but i don't want to users to use these credit.

Is there any way to users can use their free AI hub trial credits instead of Organization.

Note : Currently each users are mapped to dev environment and they are unable to signup for free AI hub trial